# Show all services on right click (mac)

Tags: macos, automator

Whenever you have more than 4 services, they are put in a dropdown option "Services" on right click instead of just being added to the right click menu itself.

Is this an option somewhere that can be changed?

Thanks.

Comment: Please do not cross post questions on different Stack Exchange sites. As your question’s best fit is Ask Different, [where you also posted it](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/79955/show-all-services-on-right-click), I’ve flagged the SU version for deletion.

Comment: @kopischke Thanks for bringing this to our attention, but OS X questions are absolutely on topic here—saying it's best fit somewhere else is debatable. The OP can choose where to post. In this case, I'll close it for the time being, but if Wesley would like to keep the version here, we can also close the Apple.SE version.

Comment: @slhck absolutely, which is why I didn’t go for ‘Off Topic’. I should have stated more clearly that in my experience, this kind of question has a *better* chance of finding a good answer on Ask than on SU. Bad choice of words when saying ‘deletion’, too, I realise, a bit late.

Comment: [Answered on Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/79955/show-all-services-on-right-click).